# Translate sorted key lambda with negative value in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I currently use the following, and iterate through it in the appropriate order:

`sorted(array.items(), key=lambda i: -i[1])`

I have tried to substitute this with np.apply_along_axis but I am not getting the same results.

How would the same exact thing be written in numpy?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. You're sorting a `dict` called `array` based on its value and getting a list of tuples? You want to use np to turn a dictionary into a list of tuples, or were you looking for a 2d array? Can you include some sample input and output for clarity?

Comment: @HenryEcker Currently array is a dict and the output is a list of tuples indeed, I am looking for the closest match to switch over to numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

```py
import numpy as np

d = {1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 9, 4: 0, 5: -1}

arr = np.array(list(d.items()))
```

---

Output as 2d numpy array:

```py
print(arr[(-arr[:, 1]).argsort()])
```

```
[[ 3  9]
 [ 2  5]
 [ 1  3]
 [ 4  0]
 [ 5 -1]]
```

---

Output as list of numpy arrays:

```py
print(sorted(arr, key=lambda row: -row[1]))
```

```
[array([3, 9]), array([2, 5]), array([1, 3]), array([4, 0]), array([ 5, -1])]
```

---

Output as list of tuples (exact match to sorted items)

```
print(list(map(tuple, arr[(-arr[:, 1]).argsort()])))
```

OR

```
print(list(map(tuple, sorted(arr, key=lambda row: -row[1]))))
```

```
[(3, 9), (2, 5), (1, 3), (4, 0), (5, -1)]
```